# Add specific word after last slash in all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a *MySQL Server* and I'm trying put a specific word after the last slash in all rows

```
** table **
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/187500461.mp4
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/187500462.mp4
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/187500463.mp4
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/187500464.mp4
```

I need add "/p1/" after the last slash. The result should be something like this:

```
** table **
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/p1/187500461.mp4
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/p1/187500462.mp4
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/p1/187500463.mp4
http://link.com/prop/datadelivery/sys/p1/187500464.mp4
```

I took a look in command "replace" but I believe that it might be not the ideal solution for me in this case.
Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: show us how you took in `replace` ...

Comment: `update names
    set name = replace(name, '/sys', '/sys/p1/')
    where name like '%/sys/';` but is not working properly

Comment: what about using `replace(str,'/sys','/sys/p1')` by removing last slash only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. add `%` after `%/sys/` otherwise, you will not match any data. because those data have data after `/sys`.

```
update T 
set name = replace(name, '/sys/', '/sys/p1/') 
where name like '%/sys/%';
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8xb1cuxKMWFm8Z5c5c7DQw/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`locate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to find the position of a substring in a string. The only problem is, that it returns the first position of the substring. You you'll have to work on [`reverse()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse)d strings, to get the last one. With [`substring()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) you can then cut out the substrings before and after the last `'/'` and [`contat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) it back together including your addendum. Of course you need to re-reverse it in the end.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET nmuloc = reverse(concat(substring(reverse(nmuloc), 1, locate('/', reverse(nmuloc))),
                            reverse('p1'),
                            substring(reverse(nmuloc), locate('/', reverse(nmuloc)))));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b10e447100c40d1f0c42f76a71df1861)